# Elasticsearch nested field: nested query inside must vs must inside nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm performing range query on a nested field `task__distributions`.

The first one places two nested query inside must query.
The second one performs the must query inside one nested query.

I thought these two would return same result but I'm getting correct result for the second query only (returning no result).

Is there any difference between these two query?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "task__distributions",
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "task__distributions.publishDate": {
                                    "gte": "2021-09-30T18:00:00.000Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "task__distributions",
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "task__distributions.publishDate": {
                                    "lte": "2021-10-31T17:59:59.999Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "task__distributions",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "task__distributions.publishDate": {
                                    "gte": "2021-09-30T18:00:00.000Z"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "task__distributions.publishDate": {
                                    "lte": "2021-10-31T17:59:59.999Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a significant difference between those two queries. Important is the level of the nested query.
In the first query, the two nested queries are independent from each other and can match different nested objects, in the second query the two must queries are applied two the same nested object.

Trying to describe the queries in natural language:

1. Match all documents which contain a task distribution with publish date *gte* 2021-09-30 AND contain a task distribution with publish date *lte* 2021-10-31.
2. Match all documents that have a task distribution with a publish date *gte* 2021-09-30 AND *lte* 2021-10-31

So let's assume we have this document:

```
    "_source" : {
      "task__distribution" : [
        {
          "task" : "123",
          "publish_date" : "2021-09-01T18:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "task" : "234",
          "publish_date" : "2021-11-01T18:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The first query would match, because the first nested field (task 123) has a publish date *gte* 2021-09-30 AND the second nested field (task 234) a task distribution with publish date *lte* 2021-10-31.

However, the second query wouldn't match this document, because none of those two publish dates is between the two given dates. This is your desired behaviour.

You can check out [Nested query doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) for more details.

The reason for this behavior can be explained from the Documentation:

> The nested query searches nested field objects as if they were indexed as separate documents. If an object matches the search, the nested query returns the root parent document.