# Elastic Search Querying nested objects in same context

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a similar issue like : [Elasticsearch nested field: nested query inside must vs must inside nested query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470243/elasticsearch-nested-field-nested-query-inside-must-vs-must-inside-nested-query)

But I need to query nested object in same context in multiple different sub query blocks

Is there a possibility?

I've checked and it seems there are only ways to boost the result based for the subqueries but I want only the parent documents that match both the subquery constraints

Comment: Combine both constraints with a bool query within the same nested query

Comment: I have a use case that they will appear in different parts of the overall query, and hence I won't be able to use them inside the same nested query @Val

Comment: You should explain your different use cases, otherwise it's difficult to help

Comment: My use case is, I have end user defined dynamic filters and it will have multiple nested queries for same objects, so I have to return the parent document only when all conditions are met by the query

Comment: I can create a gist for the full scenario if required more info

Comment: Help us help you! The more info you can share, the better